# Oracle SQL Selecting rows from one table not in another

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

can anyone help me with my sql statement below. What i am trying to do is retrieve rows from 1 table where they do not appear within the date range of another table. The query below at the moment returns the row that is between the date range entered. How could i modify it so that the rows not between the date range in table 2 are returned from table 1? table 1 would be homes and table 2 would be bookings

```
SELECT homes.home_id, homes.title, homes.description, homes.living_room_count, homes.bedroom_count, homes.bathroom_count, homes.price, homes.sqft,
listagg(features.feature_name, '\n') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY features.feature_name) features, home_type.type_name
FROM homes
INNER JOIN bookings ON bookings.home_id = homes.home_id
INNER JOIN home_feature ON homes.home_id = home_feature.home_id
INNER JOIN home_type ON home_type.type_code = homes.type_code
INNER JOIN features ON home_feature.feature_id = features.feature_id
WHERE bookings.booking_end < to_date('23-Jan-13')
OR bookings.booking_start > to_date('22-Jan-13')
GROUP BY homes.home_id, homes.title, homes.description, homes.living_room_count, homes.bedroom_count, homes.bathroom_count, homes.price, homes.sqft, home_type.type_name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use a `LEFT JOIN` to return all rows from `homes` that do not appear in `bookings`. I would also suggest moving the `bookings.date` filter from the `WHERE` clause to the `JOIN` condition:

```
SELECT homes.home_id, 
    homes.title, 
    homes.description, 
    homes.living_room_count, 
    homes.bedroom_count, 
    homes.bathroom_count, 
    homes.price, homes.sqft,
   listagg(features.feature_name, '\n') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY features.feature_name) features, 
    home_type.type_name
FROM homes
LEFT JOIN bookings 
   ON bookings.home_id = homes.home_id
   AND (bookings.booking_end < to_date('23-Jan-13')
    OR bookings.booking_start > to_date('22-Jan-13'))
LEFT JOIN home_feature 
  ON homes.home_id = home_feature.home_id
LEFT JOIN home_type 
  ON home_type.type_code = homes.type_code
LEFT JOIN features 
  ON home_feature.feature_id = features.feature_id
GROUP BY homes.home_id, homes.title, 
    homes.description, homes.living_room_count, 
    homes.bedroom_count, homes.bathroom_count, 
    homes.price, homes.sqft, home_type.type_name
```

Based on your comment, you can try a `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT homes.home_id, 
    homes.title, 
    homes.description, 
    homes.living_room_count, 
    homes.bedroom_count, 
    homes.bathroom_count, 
    homes.price, homes.sqft,
   listagg(features.feature_name, '\n') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY features.feature_name) features, 
    home_type.type_name
FROM homes
INNER JOIN home_feature 
  ON homes.home_id = home_feature.home_id
INNER JOIN home_type 
  ON home_type.type_code = homes.type_code
INNER JOIN features 
  ON home_feature.feature_id = features.feature_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT home_id
                  FROM bookings b
                  WHERE b.home_id = homes.home_id
                    AND (b.booking_end < to_date('23-Jan-13')
                      OR b.booking_start > to_date('22-Jan-13'))
GROUP BY homes.home_id, homes.title, 
    homes.description, homes.living_room_count, 
    homes.bedroom_count, homes.bathroom_count, 
    homes.price, homes.sqft, home_type.type_name
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. i tried your query and it returns all the rows from the homes table when one, between the date range should be omitted.

Comment: @user1851487 Oops, missed that in your explanation. See my edit